# application only inserts one row

Tags: java, oracle, foreach, insert, mybatis

I'm developing an application and when I make a single insert inserts a single row with data.
I made various tests and can not find the solution please help

```
public boolean cargaModalidad(String textArchivo)
{
        logger.debug("Correcto3");

        //parseoArchivoModalidad(textArchivo);


        logger.debug("Correcto3.1");
    //boolean paso =true;
    //ingresoModalidadATabla.insertModalidad(paso);
//  return paso =true;

//public void parseoArchivoModalidad()throws IOException{

    logger.debug("Correcto4.3");
    FinTramiteModalidadList finTramiteModList = new FinTramiteModalidadList();
    logger.debug("Entrada:"+textArchivo);


            Integer n=0;
            String linea;

            ArrayList<String> linea1 = new ArrayList<String>();

            logger.debug("Correcto4.4");

    //String datosText= (textArchivo);

    try {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(textArchivo.getBytes());


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            linea1.add(n,linea.trim());

            n=n+1;
            System.out.println(linea);


    for(String fila:linea1)
    {
            String numeroArt06 = fila.substring(236,242);
            int aux ;
            FinTramiteModalidadAtributos finTramiteModAtributos = new FinTramiteModalidadAtributos();
            logger.debug("Correcto4");
            if(fila!=null && fila !="" && fila.length()==628  && fila.substring(0,1).equals("D"))
            {
                logger.debug("Correcto5");
            finTramiteModAtributos.setTipoReg(fila.substring(0, 1));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setRutAfil(fila.substring(1,9));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setDigRut(fila.substring(9,10));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setTipOper(fila.substring(10,11));

            //Agregando parseo 1
            finTramiteModAtributos.setApePatAfi(fila.substring(11,41));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setApeMatAfi(fila.substring(41,71));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setNombresAfi(fila.substring(71,101));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setCodAfp(fila.substring(101,105));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setCodIsapre(fila.substring(105,109));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setDireccion(fila.substring(109,159));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setComuna(fila.substring(159,189));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setCiudad(fila.substring(189,219));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setRegion(fila.substring(219,223));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setCodIsapreCon(fila.substring(223,227));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setTipoPension(fila.substring(227,229));

            finTramiteModAtributos.setModalidad(fila.substring(229,231));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setNumAgnosDiff(fila.substring(231,233));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setMesGarantizado(fila.substring(233,236));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setArt06(fila.substring(236,242).replace(".",","));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setFecCierre(fila.substring(242,250));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setHoraCierre(fila.substring(250,256));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setNumSolOferta(fila.substring(256,266));

            //FIN agregando parseo 1
            //13 datos 
            finTramiteModAtributos.setNumIdOfertaSel(fila.substring(266,278));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setSecOfertaSel(fila.substring(278,280));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setSecOfertaIntRel(fila.substring(280,282));

            finTramiteModAtributos.setIndOfertaExt(fila.substring(282,283));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setNumCotOfertaExt(fila.substring(283,303));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setNumSolRemAdj(fila.substring(303,313));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setMtoPenRvUf(fila.substring(313,325).replace(".",","));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setPorComRv(fila.substring(325,331).replace(".",","));

            finTramiteModAtributos.setPlazoRemPolAfp(fila.substring(331,339));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setSaldoUfFA(fila.substring(339,351).replace(".",","));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setSaldoUfFB(fila.substring(351,363).replace(".",","));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setSaldoUfFC(fila.substring(363,375).replace(".",","));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setSaldoUfFD(fila.substring(375,387).replace(".",","));

            // PARSEO 2
            finTramiteModAtributos.setSaldoUfFE(fila.substring(387,399).replace(".",","));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setTipPartSel(fila.substring(399,400));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setRutPartCiasegSel(fila.substring(400,408));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setDvPartCiasegSel(fila.substring(408,409));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setRazonSocialPartCiaseg(fila.substring(409,439));

            finTramiteModAtributos.setTipInter(fila.substring(439,440));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setRutIntermediario(fila.substring(440,448));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setDvIntermediario(fila.substring(448,449));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setNombreIntermediario(fila.substring(449,499));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setRutApoderado(fila.substring(499,507));

            finTramiteModAtributos.setDvApoderado(fila.substring(507,508));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setNombreApoderado(fila.substring(508,558));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setPorHonRpRt(fila.substring(558,564).replace(".",","));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setValHonRpRtUf(fila.substring(564,576).replace(".",","));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setCodAfpSel(fila.substring(576,580));
            //uLTIMO PARSEO

            finTramiteModAtributos.setMtoPenRpRtUf(fila.substring(580,592).replace(".",","));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setTipTransBono(fila.substring(592,593));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setValorBonoUf(fila.substring(593,605).replace(".",","));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setNumCotOfertaExt2(fila.substring(605,625));
            finTramiteModAtributos.setMesesDiferido(fila.substring(625,628));


            finTramiteModList.getFinTram().add(finTramiteModAtributos);

            logger.debug("Correcto6");
            System.out.println("Los datos del Tipo Reg son: '"+finTramiteModAtributos.getTipoReg()+"'");
            System.out.println("Los datos del Rut Afi son: '"+finTramiteModAtributos.getRutAfil()+"'");
            System.out.println("Los datos del Dig Rut son: '"+finTramiteModAtributos.getDigRut()+"'");
            System.out.println("Los datos del Tip Oper son: '"+finTramiteModAtributos.getTipOper()+"'");

            }


            } 
 logger.debug("Correcto7");

return (ingresoModalidadATabla.insertModalidad(finTramiteModList.getFinTram()) > 0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.debug("Correcto8");
    return false;

}
```

This is where I'm sending data list:

```
public class FinTramiteModalidadList {

private List<FinTramiteModalidadAtributos> finTram;

public FinTramiteModalidadList()
{
this.setFinTram(new ArrayList<FinTramiteModalidadAtributos>());
}

public List<FinTramiteModalidadAtributos> getFinTram() {
    return finTram;
}

public void setFinTram(List<FinTramiteModalidadAtributos> finTram) {
    this.finTram = finTram;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
String retorno = "";
for(FinTramiteModalidadAtributos nodo:this.finTram){
    retorno = retorno + nodo.toString();
}
return retorno;

}
```

This is the XML file where I'm doing the insert

```
<insert id="insertModalidad" useGeneratedKeys="true" parameterType="java.util.List">

                     INSERT INTO STP_FTSELSCOMP     (TIPO_REG,  RUT_AFIL, DIG_RUT,  TIP_OPER,   APE_PAT_AFI,

                                                    APE_MAT_AFI,    NOMBRES_AFI,    COD_AFP,    COD_ISAPRE, DIRECCION,

                                                    COMUNA, CIUDAD, REGION, COD_ISAPRE_CON, TIPO_PENSION,

                                                    MODALIDAD,  NUM_AGNOS_DIFF, MES_GARANTIZADO,ART_06, FEC_CIERRE,

                                                    HORA_CIERRE,    NUM_SOL_OFERTA, NUM_ID_OFERTA_SEL,SEC_OFERTA_SEL , SEC_OFERTA_INT_REL, 

                                                    IND_OFERTA_EXT, NUM_COT_OFERTA_EXT,NUM_SOL_REM_ADJ,MTO_PEN_RV_UF, POR_COM_RV, 

                                                    PLAZO_REM_POL_AFP,SALDO_UF_F_A, SALDO_UF_F_B,SALDO_UF_F_C, SALDO_UF_F_D,

                                                    SALDO_UF_F_E, TIP_PART_SEL, RUT_PART_CIASEG_SEL, DV_PART_CIASEG_SEL,RAZON_SOCIAL_PART_CIASEG, 

                                                    TIP_INTER, RUT_INTERMEDIARIO, DV_INTERMEDIARIO,NOMBRE_INTERMEDIARIO,RUT_APODERADO, 

                                                    DV_APODERADO, NOMBRE_APODERADO, POR_HON_RP_RT, VAL_HON_RP_RT_UF,COD_AFP_SEL,

                                                    MTO_PEN_RP_RT_UF,TIP_TRANS_BONO, VALOR_BONO_UF,NUM_COT_OFERTA_EXT2,MESES_DIFERIDO   ) VALUES  

                                   <foreach collection="list" item="modalidades" open="(" close=")" separator=",">
                                              #{modalidades.tipoReg},        
                                              #{modalidades.rutAfil}, 
                                              #{modalidades.digRut},
                                              #{modalidades.tipOper},
                                              #{modalidades.apePatAfi}, 
                                              #{modalidades.apeMatAfi}, 
                                              #{modalidades.nombresAfi}, 
                                              #{modalidades.codAfp}, 
                                              #{modalidades.codIsapre}, 
                                              #{modalidades.direccion}, 
                                              #{modalidades.comuna}, 
                                              #{modalidades.ciudad}, 
                                              #{modalidades.region}, 
                                              #{modalidades.codIsapreCon}, 
                                              #{modalidades.tipoPension},
                                              #{modalidades.modalidad},
                                              #{modalidades.numAgnosDiff},
                                              #{modalidades.mesGarantizado},
                                              #{modalidades.art06},
                                              #{modalidades.fecCierre},
                                              #{modalidades.horaCierre},
                                              #{modalidades.numSolOferta},

                                              #{modalidades.numIdOfertaSel},
                                              #{modalidades.secOfertaSel},
                                              #{modalidades.secOfertaIntRel},
                                              #{modalidades.indOfertaExt},
                                              #{modalidades.numCotOfertaExt},
                                              #{modalidades.numSolRemAdj},
                                              #{modalidades.mtoPenRvUf},
                                              #{modalidades.porComRv},
                                              #{modalidades.plazoRemPolAfp},
                                              #{modalidades.saldoUfFA},
                                              #{modalidades.saldoUfFB},
                                              #{modalidades.saldoUfFC},
                                              #{modalidades.saldoUfFD},

                                              #{modalidades.saldoUfFE},
                                              #{modalidades.tipPartSel},
                                              #{modalidades.rutPartCiasegSel},
                                              #{modalidades.dvPartCiasegSel},
                                              #{modalidades.razonSocialPartCiaseg},
                                              #{modalidades.tipInter},
                                              #{modalidades.rutIntermediario},
                                              #{modalidades.dvIntermediario},
                                              #{modalidades.nombreIntermediario},
                                              #{modalidades.rutApoderado},
                                              #{modalidades.dvApoderado},
                                              #{modalidades.nombreApoderado},
                                              #{modalidades.porHonRpRt},
                                              #{modalidades.valHonRpRtUf},
                                              #{modalidades.codAfpSel},

                                              #{modalidades.mtoPenRpRtUf},
                                              #{modalidades.tipTransBono},
                                              #{modalidades.valorBonoUf},
                                              #{modalidades.numCotOfertaExt2},
                                              #{modalidades.mesesDiferido}


                                        </foreach> 
                     </insert>
```

Comment: Please make sure to format your code properly. Use the preview to verify it outputs correctly.

Comment: There is no code with MyBatis.